# Cygwin git removes excutable flag

Tags: git, cygwin

I'm using cygwin git. The files in the repository are partly executable, sometimes because someone just accidentally set the executable flag and sometimes because it's a shell script which intentionally should be executable. When I clone the repository cygwin git afterwards lists the executable files with changed permissions: The executable flag has been removed. So I end up with lots of changed files without actually having done something. In other threads I saw recommendations to just switch off the handling of file permissions via filemode=false in the git config. But I wonder if there is no other solution. Using the cygwin shell permissions seem fine. Only git lists the file permissions as changed.

Comment: which repository ? How we can replicate your problem ?

Comment: For me the issue occurs with any repository that contains files that are flagged executable. But I just noticed that only git gui is affected. When running git status no files are listed changed. I'm using cygwin 64, git version is 2.28.0.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [a common mistake where people try to use git as a (sort of a) deployment tool](https://grimoire.ca/git/stop-using-git-pull-to-deploy/). Git is a VCS - version control system. It records changes to your source code and that's its primary purpose. Deployment-specific stuff, like file permissions, built output files (dlls) from your source files, environment-specific configuration files, etc., should not be versioned with git, since that's not part of the source code. It's part of the deployment process. This answer will sound discouraging at first, but once you stop using git for what it wasn't designed, you'll find a lot better tools for that and with all combined, I hope you'll end up having each tool doing its job perfectly, the way it was designed for, making your development/deployment process a lot less stressful.

Comment: My use case is not about deployment. It's about bash helper scripts e.g. used in the build process but also for other purposes. They definitely should be versioned and when the repository is cloned they should get the executable flag set automatically.